# Solution to a Set of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if there is a solution to the following set of differential equations

$\frac{d}{dt} A = AB,$

$\Delta B =0,$

$B \rightarrow -1$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$

$A \rightarrow e^{-t}$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$

where $A$ and $B$ are functions of $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ and $r= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.  The obvious trivial solution is $A=e^{-t}$ and $B=-1$, but I was wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want $\Delta B = \nabla \cdot \nabla B = 0$, i.e. $B$ is harmonic?

Comment: Yes, $\Delta$ is the regular Laplacian in this case so $B$ is harmonic.